# PowerShell ISE won't let me set breakpoints when running as Administrator

Tags: powershell

I'm running Powershell ISE as local administrator on Windows Server 2012 R2. The Toggle Breakpoint F9 is greyed out. It looks like with this account, it is bypassing UAC and thus running "as Administrator".
I am opening an existing script file to run and it does not have brackets [] in the file name/path anywhere. Any other ideas to explain what's going on here?

Edit: I just installed the Visual Studio Code editor and it does the same thing. F9 is not greyed out in the menu, but it does not set a breakpoint. Again, this only happens when logged in as the built-in administrator.

Comment: I've never seen this issue and I run my PowerShell sessions (console host/ISE/VSCode/Sapien's PowerShell Studio and Visual Studio) as administrator by default. What are you selecting? Show your code? Yet as we know, the ISE is what it is and no more effort is going into it.  So, if you continue to have this issue, your option is to move to VSCode and fully set it up as your PowerShell development environment. If allowed on those servers, of course. I've not been in an enterprise to date that allows that except on workstations.

Comment: What do you get when you use the examples from here: [How to Debug Scripts in Windows PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.1#:~:text=%20You%20can%20set%20three%20types%20of%20breakpoints,command%20is%20about%20to%20be%20run...%20More%20)?

Comment: Someone asked this same question 4 years ago "Why won't PowerShell ISE let me set breakpoints when running as Administrator" and their problem was brackets in the file name. The code is irrelevant since it's the ISE that's having a problem. And this only happens when I'm logged in with the built-in Administrator account. Running as my own domain account is fine. Problem is, I'm trying to develop a script that will be run by VMware's invoke-vmscript and it runs without elevation unless I'm using the built-in admin. That's either a failure of VMware or of the existence of User Account Control.

Comment: Again, as per my response showing the results, admin or not, you can set breakpoints and debug as normal. Why anyone would have brackets/braces other PowerShell reserved characters in their file names is a different matter. Anything I submit here is on a standalone machine, running PowerShell as admin, not using the builtin admin, which really should never be used for normal user actions. It's disabled by default after an OS install for a reason, with little need to enable it back and that account is a known security risk for years, even MS says don't use it. So, again, an env issue.

Comment: To use this account, you had to explicitly enable that account and give it a password to use it like you are trying to. This account has no access to anything other than your local machine. Outside of pristine builds OS/OS recovery, this built-in admin account should not be enabled at all. So, developing with it to use on enterprise targets is moot.  Dev the script with a normal user local admin account or your domain admin account. Set the script to run via a scheduled task to use a higher privilege/different account for elevation needs.

Comment: Without using this account, I cannot create a task that runs as system. That's what I'm trying to do. To get the abilities that this account affords with another account, I would have to disable User Account Control. Obviously anyone focused on maximum security wouldn't recommend that either. So, I guess the real issue is, how can one run commands that require system account via PowerCLI on a VM? But none of that answers the question of why the GUI breakpoints and step through is or could be somehow disabled by using one account over another. Your suggestion was to use commands, not the GUI.

Comment: As for [Without using this account, I cannot create a task that runs as a system.], this is not valid. You can use a normal admin account and use MS Sysinternal PSExec to run as a system. Again, run as NTSytem using a scheduled task to avoid other external tools. This is a Windows Security boundary that PowerShell respects and PowerShell only runs in the context of the normal user account identity that started. The default built-in admin is not a normal user account. For example, if you set a shortcut properties to 'Run as Admin', is not the same as RIght-Click RunAsAdmin.

Comment: Actually, I had trouble using Psexec. I tried that first and it didn't really work either.